# UDP Broadcast Messages to all nodes in OMNET++

Tags: c++, udp, broadcast, omnet++, application-layer

I am using OMNET++ INET for Ad hoc networks.
I want to broadcast my message to all my neighbors in UDP. I have tried all the possible solutions in UDPBasicApp. It broadcasts a message to one node at a time which it chooses randomly if the destination is not fixed (sink). UDPBasicBurstApp also does not send message to all connected nodes.

Comment: Could you precise "*all my neighbors in UDP*"? UDP works in transport layer. There is no neighbors in that layer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with a real network: to broadcast to all nodes on your local network you must use the local broadcast address as a destination address.

i.e. if I'm on the network 192.168.0.0 and I have an 8 bit subnet then sending to 192.168.0.255 would broadcast the message.

Answer (score 0):

sorry in my omnet.ini file I have this configuration:

*.configurator.config = xml("")
*.configurator.optimizeRoutes = false
*.host*.ipv4.routingTable.netmaskRoutes = ""

I would like to send the UDP packet to multiple end nodes so that they all receive the same packet and not that the end node is chosen randomly. How should I set the destAddress?